# How to create a sequence of up to 200-500 thousands numbers in just few microseconds

Tags: r, seq

I need to create a sequence of numbers in the shortest amount of time, ideally in the microseconds range. The total length of this sequence is generally in the range of 20-100 thousand numbers, but sometimes I need to create a sequence of 200-300 thousands numbers.
For the moment I have implemented my code in R (just because I know the language fairly well).
Assuming my sequence should start from 1 and end up to 25, with an increment of 0.0001, in R I would do

```
s <- seq(1, 25, by = 0.0001)
```

Although blazingly fast, this takes few milliseconds to complete

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(seq(1, 25, by = 0.0001))
Unit: milliseconds
                   expr    min      lq     mean median     uq     max neval
 seq(1, 25, by = 1e-04) 1.6098 2.14505 3.741858 2.2324 2.3554 83.8912   100
```

Here my questions:

1- is it possible to make the sequence generation faster in R? ideally < 0.5 milliseconds?

2- at some point I would need to implement the code in another (faster) language, would any language able to generate such a sequences in less then 100-200 microseconds?

Comment: I believe the answer to both questions is yes, it is possible to make `seq.default` faster. 1) In your use case you only have arguments `from`, `to` and `by`, `seq.default` has more. And if you know in advance that `from < to && by > 0` you will be able to simplify the original code. 2) `seq.default` is written in pure R, take a look at package `Rcpp` for ways of using `C++` from R. Or write a shared lib in C, C++ and load it when needed, for instance, included in a R package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Rcpp` you can improve the speed by ~ 60%. Though, still not "a few" µseconds.

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)

cppFunction(
  "
  NumericVector cpp_seq(double &from, double &to, double &by){
    int length = abs((to - from) / by);

    NumericVector out(length + 1);
    int pos = 0;

    for (double i = from; i < to; i += by){
      out[pos] = i;
      pos +=1;
    }

    out[length] = to;
    return out;
  }
  "
)

x <- cpp_seq(1, 25, 0.0001)

microbenchmark(
  seq = seq(1, 25, 0.0001),
  cpp_seq = cpp_seq(1, 25, 0.0001), 
  times = 1000
)

# Unit: microseconds
#     expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#     seq  2425.694 2630.6595 4262.708 2847.697 3256.618 99978.10  1000
# cpp_seq   670.949  794.6625 1239.710  903.714 1005.736 12892.09  1000
```

Both vectors are the same, when you account for floating point errors:

```
x_R <- seq(1, 25, 0.0001)
x_cpp <- cpp_seq(1, 25, 0.0001)

identical(round(x_R, 9), round(x_cpp, 9))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: this will do it for now, thanks. As I said, at some point I will have to move to another language. I guess a language that support concurrency would be a good choice. Not an expert on this topic, but maybe a way to make it faster would be to split the from-to range in chunks and do the operation in parallel on the sub-ranges...

Answer (score 2):

`seq.int()` is 30-40% faster..

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  seq = seq(1, 25, by = 0.0001),
  seq.int = seq.int(1, 250000, by = 1) / 10000
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
#     seq 2.0749 2.16525 3.375812 2.2222 2.31935 95.9553   100
# seq.int 1.3184 1.35860 1.458503 1.3855 1.42940  6.9268   100
```

Also, beware of the floaring point errors!!

```
sprintf("%.100f", seq(0,0.01,0.0001) )
  [1] "0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  [2] "0.0001000000000000000047921736023859295983129413798451423645019531250000000000000000000000000000000000"
  [3] "0.0002000000000000000095843472047718591966258827596902847290039062500000000000000000000000000000000000"
  [4] "0.0003000000000000000279290479632265942200319841504096984863281250000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  [5] "0.0004000000000000000191686944095437183932517655193805694580078125000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  [6] "0.0005000000000000000104083408558608425664715468883514404296875000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  [7] "0.0006000000000000000558580959264531884400639683008193969726562500000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: I commented this - note also that the 'int' in `seq.int()` means internal not integer so you don't need to use integers and divide, fractional sequences are fine.

Comment: @H1, so i see , hadn't read the comments..... you can add your comment as an answer if you want, so I can delete mine...
I was under the assumption that the deviding would prevent floating point errors.. but this seems to be wrong....

Comment: thanks for pointing out the floating point issue, did not think about it. Fortunately for now I am interested in the first 4 decimals, but this could easily change in the future, and I would have spent a bit of time before realizing it